# REST on JMS Transport instead of HTTP

Tags: rest, jms, cxf, spring-jms, cxfrs

I'm trying to create multiple channels for REST such that my endpoints can be invoked from Browser using http protcol or other applications can asynchronously invoke by placing message on queue. Though I'm able to configure both transport types. I'm able to access the REST service and but fails when sending JMS message.

Here is the complete code setup I'm using for reproducing the issue.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.kp.swasthik</groupId>
    <artifactId>kp-rest-jms-artemis</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>kp-rest-jms-artemis</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <cxf.version>3.1.10</cxf.version>
        <!-- <artemis.version>2.0.0</artemis.version> -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-jms-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**REST Service**

```
@Service
@Path("/kp")
public class KPRest {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @POST
    @Path("/hello")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello(String hello){
        System.out.println(hello);
        return "Hello from CXF";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/send-message")
    public String sendMessage(){
        jmsTemplate.send("cxf_queue", (session)->{
            TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage();
            msg.setBooleanProperty("OnewayMessage", true);
            msg.setStringProperty("org.apache.cxf.message.Message.REQUEST_URI", "/kp/hello");
            msg.setText("JMS message");
            return msg;
        });
        return "Sent message";
    }

}
```

**Cxf Configuration**

import com.kp.swasthik.cxf.rest.KPRest;

```
@Configuration
public class CxfConfig {

    @Bean
    public Server jaxrsServerRest(Bus bus, KPRest rest){
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean server = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        server.setAddress("/kp");
        server.setBus(bus);
        server.setServiceBean(rest);
        server.setFeatures(Arrays.asList(new LoggingFeature()));
        return server.create();
    }

    @Bean
    public Server jaxrsServerJMS(Bus bus, KPRest rest, JMSConfigFeature feature){
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean server = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        server.setAddress("/");
        server.setTransportId("http://cxf.apache.org/transports/jms");
        server.setBus(bus);
        server.setServiceBean(rest);
        server.setFeatures(Arrays.asList(new LoggingFeature(), feature));
        return server.create();
    }

    @Bean
    public JMSConfigFeature getJMSFeature(JMSConfiguration jmsConfiguration) {
        JMSConfigFeature feature = new JMSConfigFeature();
        feature.setJmsConfig(jmsConfiguration);
        return feature;
    }

    @Bean
    public JMSConfiguration getjmsConfig(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        JMSConfiguration config = new JMSConfiguration();
        config.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        config.setTargetDestination("cxf_queue");
        return config;
    }
}
```

**Spring Boot starter class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class KpRestJmsArtimisApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KpRestJmsArtimisApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.artemis.embedded.queues=cxf_queue
spring.artemis.embedded=true
```

I'm calling send-message rest api which places the message in `cxf_queue` which would be read by the CXF endpoint. However I get error due to the presence of `.` in the `org.apache.cxf.message.Message.REQUEST_URI`

Here is stacktrace.

```
javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException: AMQ129012: The property name 'org.apache.cxf.message.Message.REQUEST_URI' is not a valid java identifier.
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessage.checkProperty(ActiveMQMessage.java:919) ~[artemis-jms-client-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessage.setStringProperty(ActiveMQMessage.java:657) ~[artemis-jms-client-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at com.kp.swasthik.cxf.rest.KPRest.lambda$0(KPRest.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:593) ~[spring-jms-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$4.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:574) ~[spring-jms-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:484) ~[spring-jms-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:570) ~[spring-jms-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.kp.swasthik.cxf.rest.KPRest.sendMessage(KPRest.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180) ~[cxf-core-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:189) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[cxf-core-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) ~[cxf-core-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:262) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:299) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:223) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:274) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
```

Not sure Cxf Completely supports REST with JMS transport type. though in the documentation it say it supports but I don't see much details in that. And also not sure if there are any way or property to escape `.` character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CXF implementation is currently not following the JMS spec. I will take care we fix this while maintaining compatibility with old CXF clients.

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-7344

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the full context of what you are trying to do, but this...

```
'org.apache.cxf.message.Message.REQUEST_URI' is not a valid java identifier.
```

...is pretty clear. You can't do this...

```
msg.setStringProperty("org.apache.cxf.message.Message.REQUEST_URI", "/kp/hello");
```

...because JMS properties can't have `.` in them - they use the same rules as java identifiers (e.g. variables).

You could replace the `.` with `_` on the sending side and swap them back on the receiving side; if you need it in that format.

Comment: Thanks for the response, searching through net, how to escape `.` but even though I  replace with _, the There are other properties which CXF sets with . resulting in same error. Hence not sure if I need to enable something in CXF to escape the characters.