# The code below can only be invoked via JMS. Modify it so that it is a web service as well

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms

The code below can only be invoked via JMS. Modify it so that it is a web service as well.

```
@MessageDriven(name = "testMDB", activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queue/test") 
})

public class MessageOne implements MessageListener {
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        Process(i);
    }
}

private void Process(int i) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(5000); //This sleep represents really complex code that takes 5 seconds to run and cannot be further optimised                              
}
}
```

Comment: When you say, "Modify it so that it is a web service *as well*," do you mean that it needs to receive JMS messages *and* web service requests?

Comment: What role does the JMS MessageListener play here and why is the question tagged with `jms` and `java-ee-6` if you just wanted a STOMP service?

Comment: @Justin excuss my first comment, you are right  I mean it needs to receive JmS messages and web service requests as well..........please advice would implementing rest on  jms transport be the best choice to do so........

Answer (score 0):

To send message from REST you can use a Simple message template for simple protocols like stomp or just `JmsTemplate`:

```java
@Controller
public class MessageOneSender implements ApplicationListener<SessionDisconnectEvent> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageOneSender.class);

    private final SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

    public MessageOne(SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate) {
        this.messagingTemplate = messagingTemplate;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/queue/test")
    @SendTo("queue/test")
    public MyDTO sendMessage(@Payload MyDTO myDTO, Principal principal) {
        // TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
        // or this way
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("queue/test", "message");
    }
}
```

The above code is for receiving a message via rest and passing It to the JMS. To reuse code from your message listener you should probably have to add @JmsListener method, move your code to the @Service and you can call it from rest & from listener method:

```java
@Component
public class MyDTOReceiver {

  @Autowired
  private MyService service;

  @JmsListener(destination = "queue/test", containerFactory = "myFactory")
  public void receiveMessage(MyDTO dto) {
    System.out.println("Received <" + dto + ">");
    service.save(dto);
  }
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Example {

  @Autowired 
  private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
  @Autowired 
  private MyService service;

  @PostMapping("/save")
  public void save(@RequestBody MyDTO dto) {
    service.save(dto);

    System.out.println("passing to another queue.");
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("queue/test2", dto);
  }
}

@Service
public class MyService {
  public void save(MyDTO dto) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Orbita ......is implementing the jmstemplate using soap or rest if not which web-service is it?

Comment: what ever you need. In this case rest. Template is just an util tool to send message to the queue or topic.

Comment: So I have decided to use rest over jms..........as per this piece from stackover flow.....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226697/rest-on-jms-transport-instead-of-http.........so I have converted the  MessageOne class into a atRestControler and also I have annoted the onMessage method with atGet .....is this correct??

Comment: Thank you, everything is starting to make sense so jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("queue/test2", dto); sents to the qeueu, then it will be ditected by the message lister to send to the consumer

Comment: Also I am having difficulty understanding how the producer and consumer would send and receive message

Comment: A scenario where you want to send to JMS queue just use producer method convertAndSend() which can be invoked from your REST service. For scenario when you want to listen for the new messages use @ Listener annotated method. To reuse your business logic, move your code to single place like @ Service class.

Comment: Thank you soo much, I understand now :)